# Run Grunt Watch without blocking the terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, gruntjs

I have a Grunt file running a concat and then a watch on that to re-concat if anything changes.

The problem is it blocks the terminal.

I am running this as a Visual Studio post build action, which means the program never launches.

Is there a way to run it so it doesn't block?

This is what my grunt file looks like:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        concat: {
            js: {
                src: ['public/app/**/*.js'],
                dest: 'public/app/app.js'
            },
            css: {
                src: ['public/app/**/*.css'],
                dest: 'public/app/app.css'
            }
        }, 
        concurrent: {
            watch: ['watch']
        },
        watch: {
            files: ['public/app/**/*.js', 'public/app/**/*.css', '!public/app/app.js', '!public/app/app.css'],
            tasks: ['concat']
        }
    });

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'concurrent:watch']);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run grunt as a process by running the command:

**On Windows**

```
start grunt
```

**On Linux**

```
grunt &
```